# Channel Entries - Skip a particular channel entry

Tags: channel-entries, entries, switch

Okay, I've got a page with a url that has the channel entry title in the URL. At the beginning of the page, I show the single article for that entry, but then underneath the article, I need to show all the other articles. So I can do this by setting dynamic="no" which reverts it to a normal channel:entries loop, but I would like this loop to skip and ignore the entry that is showing ta the top of the page.

I do not know how other to do this, but I put a if statement in my channel entries loop, but the problem is, I'm using switch to setup div's for a new row every third entry and the if statement messes with that.

I need the channel entries to ignore a particular entry, or I need a way to do a "continue" for the loop without messing with the switch count.

Here's my current code:

```
{if last_segment}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="event" orderby="date" sort="desc" status="open" category="10" dynamic="no" limit="7"}
        {if url_title != last_segment}
{switch="<div class='eventsRow'>||"}
    <div id="{url_title}" class="event {switch="|| lastEvent"}" data-count="{count}">
        <div class="pastEventConent">
            <h4>{title}</h4>
            <p>{excerpt}</p>
            <div class="copy">
                {copybox1}
            </div>
            <a data-tag="{url_title}" href="{title_permalink='events'}">View >></a>
        </div>
    </div>
{switch="||</div>"}
        {/if}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{if:else}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="event" orderby="date" sort="desc" status="open" category="10" offset="1" dynamic="no" limit="6"}
{switch="<div class='eventsRow'>||"}
    <div id="{url_title}" class="event {switch="|| lastEvent"}" data-count="{count}">
        <div class="pastEventConent">
            <h4>{title}</h4>
            <p>{excerpt}</p>
            <div class="copy">
                {copybox1}
            </div>
            <a data-tag="{url_title}" href="{title_permalink='events'}">View >></a>
        </div>
    </div>
{switch="||</div>"}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/if}
```

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Much simpler than you think! Just add `url_title="not '{segment_3}'"` to your Channel Entries tag. (Or whichever segment holds your entry's `url_title`.)

Comment: I love you!!!!!

Comment: The other issue (the conditional messing with number of items that insert div with switch='' variable), styling can also be done on the CSS side of things with help of nth-child selector. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp